# Creating a news feed application using Firebase

Tags: jquery, html, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm attempting to create a news feed application using firebase. I'm I have the basic functionality working, however there are some errors occurring.

Error 1) When you enter a name and message, and then click submit, the entry successfully logs in firebase, and then prepends into the news feed div. If I refresh the page, the entry that was previously displaying is no longer there, however it is still in the database. How can I make the entry stay visible on the page even if the page is refreshed?

Error 2) Again, when you enter a name and message, then click submit, the entry successfully logs in firebase, and then prepends into the news feed div. If I then enter a new name with a new message and click submit, the first message I posted, AND the second message I posted both duplicate in the news feed. They do not duplicate in firebase, there is still only one entry for each. I am not understanding where the duplicate is being created in my code.

Error 3) I am able to successfully delete an entry by clicking the x icon in the corner. When it's clicked, the entry is removed in firebase, and my code triggers the window to refresh. Just like in my first error, once the page refreshes the rest of the entries are no longer displayed even though they are still showing in firebase.

The database currently has one entry that I've created in it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

 // Initialize Firebase
 var config = {
  apiKey: "AIzaSyAd7fKr96e5ZEdVn5181Czw-FElJRXUouc",
  authDomain: "fraud-team-news-feed.firebaseapp.com",
  databaseURL: "https://fraud-team-news-feed.firebaseio.com",
  projectId: "fraud-team-news-feed",
  storageBucket: "fraud-team-news-feed.appspot.com",
  messagingSenderId: "393350782314"
 };

 firebase.initializeApp(config);

 var database = firebase.database();

 $("#submit").on("click", function() {
  event.preventDefault();

  var comment = $(".comment");

  var nameEntry = $("#name").val().trim();
  var messageEntry = $("#message").val().trim();

  var d = new Date();
  var year = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
  var dd = d.getDate();
  var mm = d.getMonth();
  var month = year[mm];
  var yyyy = d.getFullYear();
  var today = month + " " + dd + ", " + yyyy;

  database.ref().push({
   Name: nameEntry,
   Date: today,
   Message: messageEntry,
  });

  $("#name").val("");
  $("#message").val("");

  database.ref().on("child_added", function(snapshot) {
   var sv = snapshot.val();
      var key = snapshot.key;
      var newEntry = '<div class="row1"><div class="specialist-name">' + sv.Name + '</div><img src="https://connectme.apple.com/servlet/JiveServlet/previewBody/1508898-102-1-10580249/cross.png" class="delete-icon" id="' + key + '"></div><div class="row2"><div class="message-text">' + sv.Message + '</div></div><div class="row3"><div class="date">' + sv.Date + '</div></div>';
      newDiv = document.createElement('div');
   $(newDiv).addClass("comment").html(newEntry).prependTo($(".news-feed"));

     });

     $(".delete-icon").on("click", function() {
   console.log("clicked");
   var id = $(this).attr('id');
   console.log(id);
   var key = id;
   firebase.database().ref().child(key).remove();
         window.location.reload();
  });

 });

});
```

```css
.container {
 width: 400px;
 border-right: 1px solid black;
 font-size: 15px;
 font-family: arial;
}

.comment {
 border-bottom: 1px solid black;
 padding: 10px;
 line-height: 1.2;
}

.row1 {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: space-between;
}

.row3 {
 text-align: right;
 font-size: 13px;
 color: gray;
}

.specialist-name {
 font-weight: bold;
}

.delete-icon {
 height: 12px;
}

.new-comment-section p {
 margin-bottom: 5px;
 font-weight: bold;
 color: teal;
}

.name,
.message {
 border: 1px solid teal;
 border-radius: 5px;
 font-size: 13px;
 padding: 7px;
 width: 350px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>News Feed</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./news-feed.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">

 <div class="news-feed"></div>

 <div class="new-comment-section">

  <p>Name:</p>

  <input type="text" placeholder="Name" class="name" id="name">

  <p>Message:</p>

  <textarea type="text" placeholder="Message" class="message" id="message" rows="5"></textarea>
  <br>
  <input type="submit" value="submit" class="submit" id="submit">

 </div>

</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/5.5.4/firebase.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./news-feed.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of your errors come from the fact that you query the database **inside** the piece of code that is triggered by the button.

So:

**Error 1/** When you simply refresh the page, **you don't query the database** (unless you click the button), therefore you don't see any record. You should query the database when the page loads, see code below that proposes a possible solution.

**Error 2/** This error comes from the fact that each time you click on the button you query the entire database, because with `child_added`, "the event is (firstly) triggered once for each existing child" see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data#listen_for_child_events

**Error 3/** See error 1. Since you haven't clicked on the button, nothing is pulled from the db.

So, one possibility is to remove the database listener from the code of the button and to have it triggered when the `document` is "ready" (i.e. within `$(document).ready(function () {})`) , as follows:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {

        // Initialize Firebase
        var config = {
            apiKey: "AIzaSyAd7fKr96e5ZEdVn5181Czw-FElJRXUouc",
            authDomain: "fraud-team-news-feed.firebaseapp.com",
            databaseURL: "https://fraud-team-news-feed.firebaseio.com",
            projectId: "fraud-team-news-feed",
            storageBucket: "fraud-team-news-feed.appspot.com",
            messagingSenderId: "393350782314"
        };


        firebase.initializeApp(config);

        var database = firebase.database();

        database.ref().on("child_added", function (snapshot) {
            var sv = snapshot.val();
            console.log(snapshot.val());
            var key = snapshot.key;
            var newEntry = '<div class="row1"><div class="specialist-name">' + sv.Name + '</div><img src="https://connectme.apple.com/servlet/JiveServlet/previewBody/1508898-102-1-10580249/cross.png" class="delete-icon" id="' + key + '"></div><div class="row2"><div class="message-text">' + sv.Message + '</div></div><div class="row3"><div class="date">' + sv.Date + '</div></div>';
            newDiv = document.createElement('div');
            $(newDiv).addClass("comment").html(newEntry).prependTo($(".news-feed"));

        });

        $("#submit").on("click", function () {
            event.preventDefault();

            var comment = $(".comment");

            var nameEntry = $("#name").val().trim();
            var messageEntry = $("#message").val().trim();

            var d = new Date();
            var year = ["January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
            var dd = d.getDate();
            var mm = d.getMonth();
            var month = year[mm];
            var yyyy = d.getFullYear();
            var today = month + " " + dd + ", " + yyyy;

            database.ref().push({
                Name: nameEntry,
                Date: today,
                Message: messageEntry,
            });

            $("#name").val("");
            $("#message").val("");

            $(".delete-icon").on("click", function () {
                console.log("clicked");
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                console.log(id);
                var key = id;
                firebase.database().ref().child(key).remove();
                window.location.reload();
            });

        });

    });
```

Comment: @Devon Did you have time to look at the proposed solution?

Comment: Hi there! I just had time to look at your solution, this was extremely helpful, it makes complete sense to reference the database before clicking the button. I will try making all of the updates myself and follow up with any other questions I have. I appreciate your help!